# When it makes sense to use redux in angular2

Tags: angular, redux

I read some articles about using redux and angular2. But I don`t understand what redux is supposed to bring to angular2. Services should not be enough?

For instance, using the todo example (usually provided with redux), why not just use a service, with a `TodoService` where with methods to increase/decrease, get counts etc. `TodoService` is my single source of truth. And with DI I can access where I want.

Answer (score 0):

Redux is a pattern to do state management. It makes your statemanagement more maintainable, and easier. For a simple todo application, that might be overkill. If you don't have to manage a lot of state than it might not be a great idea. It opens a few cool doors though:

It makes [optimistic updates](http://blog.brecht.io/Cancellable-optimistic-updates-in-Angular2-and-Redux/) easier, it makes [real-time](http://blog.brecht.io/How-we-made-our-app-real-time-in-6-lines-of-code/) easier. And because of the immutable state you can optimise angular2 changedetection as well, by using the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.

Redux might look like overkill in the beginning but it has a lot of advantages. The devtools are also awesome, they make debugging a breeze.